# Restart ArcGIS Server Map Service From Command Line

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service

Is there a way to restart an ArcGIS Server v10 Map Service from the command line in Windows 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the AGSSOM utility http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16293.  It is a command linetool that works with Arc10 on both Win7 and WInServer2008.   You can start, stop, and view running services from the command line.  You can also write a batch script to schedule.  Very nice little utlity.

Comment: +1, it also comes with source so you can make it do other things.  NB: You must be a member of the "agsadmin" group to run the command.

Comment: AGSSOM is tha bomb, baby!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AGSSOM utility command line and save it to a .bat (batch file). This will allow you to do things like restart, stop, or stop groups or all web services with a double-click.